# How to get exit code from command in subexpression

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script fragment like this:

```
local SOME_VAR=$( first_command | second_command )
SECOND_COMMAND_EXIT_CODE=$?
```

But `SECOND_COMMAND_EXIT_CODE` is always zero even when `second_command` fails. It is also worth noting that `second_command` outputs multiple lines of text.

Is there a way to capture all the output of `second_command` in a variable and also capture its exit code in another variable?

Comment: FYI, all-uppercase variable names are by convention reserved for environment variables (if following the letter of POSIX, specifically for environment variables honored by system components -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace) and builtins; others should contain at least one lower-case letter.

Comment: ...now, if you're doing something else (like logging) in your "real" code that isn't reflected here, that would be a believable alternate explanation; it's easy to mistakenly modify `$?` by adding extra commands, even if those commands are intended to be noops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe:

```
foo=$(echo "hello world" | false); foo_exit=$?
echo "$foo_exit"
```

...yields `1`, not `0` as this question claims. Thus, the question's premise is false; if `second_command` fails without its exit status reflecting that, this is an issue to be brought up with its author/maintainer.

---

Per clarification in comments -- `local` is a builtin command, which, like other builtins, modifies `$?`. Thus, it's necessary to separate the commands to avoid modifying this value:

```
local foo
foo=$(echo "hello world" | false); foo_exit=$?
echo "$foo_exit"
```

Comment: My actual script used `local SOME_VAR=$( ... )` and it seems `local` affects the exit code which I did not expect.

Comment: Indeed. Use `local some_var` on its own line.